# Keras running on CPU when I have CUDA installed

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, gpu

I am trying to run `keras` and `tensorflow` in `R` but the model I am running takes forever and I think its down to the fact that `keras` is using the `CPU` and not the `GPU`.

I run the following and get these output:

```
 library(keras)
> k = backend()
> k
Module(tensorflow.python.keras.backend)
> sess = k$get_session()
2019-07-21 17:50:31.779012: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2019-07-21 17:50:31.795271: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-07-21 17:50:33.353448: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55fd3acf6f20 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-07-21 17:50:33.353969: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB, Compute Capability 7.0
2019-07-21 17:50:33.361485: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2300000000 Hz
2019-07-21 17:50:33.367751: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55fd1837ea00 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-07-21 17:50:33.367785: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-07-21 17:50:33.369113: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla V100-PCIE-16GB major: 7 minor: 0 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.38
pciBusID: 0000:3b:00.0
2019-07-21 17:50:33.369530: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-07-21 17:50:33.369699: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-07-21 17:50:33.369862: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-07-21 17:50:33.370015: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-07-21 17:50:33.370164: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-07-21 17:50:33.370313: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-07-21 17:50:33.370466: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could not dlopen library 'libcudnn.so.7'; dlerror: libcudnn.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib64/R/lib::/lib:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java/lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/lib:/usr/lib
2019-07-21 17:50:33.370484: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...
2019-07-21 17:50:33.370518: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-07-21 17:50:33.370531: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2019-07-21 17:50:33.370554: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
> sess$list_devices()
[[1]]
_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, CPU, 268435456, 11302566957811015897)

[[2]]
_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0, XLA_GPU, 17179869184, 1230880548243485174)

[[3]]
_DeviceAttributes(/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, XLA_CPU, 17179869184, 1347374981146185995)
```

I have access to this GPU `XLA_GPU`, right? but the output says

> Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The tensorflow found th device, but not the necessary files for it, If you have the cudnn and other libraries installed, add their folder path to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable (you can search the net to find how to do it)

Comment: didi you install tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions here (https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/install_keras.html): And ran `install_keras(tensorflow = "gpu")` but it still only wants to run the CPU version.

Comment: That command will not grep cudnn library files and is only to check cuda and driver install (because cudnn files are simply compressed and to install it needs to be extracted in cuda install directory) and please make sure you install/installed the right version of cudnn (this problem happens with version conflict too)

Comment: Do you have a link I can take a look at? I don`t know too much about cuda/cuDNN.

Comment: this a setup guide that i created for my self: [link](https://github.com/aa-samad/ubuntu-help/blob/master/cuda_install_tensorflow.md)